# Abort trap when trying to add char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, abort

I am trying to add multiple character arrays to a function:

```
#define ID_LEN 5
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 25
#define FALSE 0
char **orderedIds, buffer[5], idString[ID_LEN + 1], inputName[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1], inputDrinkType;
char inputDescription[240];
int i, listSize = 0, uniqueID, validated = FALSE;
```

This will run fine. However if I add one more byte to inputDescription it will give me an abort trap error:

```
char inputDescription[241];
```

Also if I add new string arrays I get the same error:

```
char inputDescription[240], newStringArray[10];
```

It is a big project with multiple files and functions, adding all the code to give the bigger picture might be a bit hard.... Does anybody know what is happening here???

**Resolved:**
It all boiled down to me not null terminating a string I was building, before using it in `strcat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Yes, but only in general

C is not a [memory safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_safety) language. It's possible to alias an object with an other accidentally; this is sometimes called a [*wild pointer* or a *dangling pointer*.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)

The problem isn't really with whether inputDescription has 240 or 241 bytes, rather, the problem is in which object is aliasing which other one and whether that causes a fatal error or a smaller problem. Small changes to your program change the memory layout and change the symptoms of the failure, but the cause is a bug in the program's source code.

If you clean up the program you will probably find the problem.

1. Have a prototype for everything
2. Turn on some or all of the compiler warnings and fix the identified problems
3. Incorporate a [memory debugger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_debugger)
4. Use a general-purpose debugger and get a traceback

Comment: Thanks @digitalross, until your answer I did not think to look elsewhere other than the variable declerations.